# How do you find the converse, inverse and contrapositive of an ∃ statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, education

My textbook shows us how to find the negation, converse, inverse and contrapositive of a universal statement, but doesn't mention anything about finding these for a ∃ statement and I can't find much online.

Can I use the negation of the ∃ statement, and then apply the same rules for finding these as you do to universal statements? Since negated it will be univeral and will be equivalent? –

Comment: You can use the fact that $\forall x \: \phi(x)$ is logically equivalent to $\neg \exists x  \: (\neg \phi(x))$

Comment: It makes sense to speak of the negation of an existential proposition, but the other constructions involve implication.  So the Question in its present form is unclear.

Comment: "*Can I use the negation of the $∃$ statement, and then apply the rules for universal statements?*" Yes, this works, and is in fact how you might *derive* the corresponding rules for universal. $\quad$ P.S. To improve your question, please explicitly state all the examples mentioned in your first paragraph.